# Sum of any values in [xx] in an excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to add numbers in [xx] brackets in an excel cell.
eg.

```
adfsaf [30] asdfsaf dsaf[40] asfdsa sadf  saf [30] asdfsafsf [30]
```

ans : 130

Comment: Can you add a helper column to help you calculate?

Answer (score 1):

Use TEXTSPLIT to split on the `[`

[image]

Then TEXTBEFORE to get the number before the `]`

[image]

Then try to make them numbers with `--` if error make it `0`

[image]

Then SUM:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"["),"]"),0))
```

[image]

---

now if they are all different cells then we replace the TEXTSPLIT with TEXTAFTER and reference the range:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"["),"]"),0))
```

[image]

Comment: You can skip the TEXTBEFORE function by including `"]"` as the `row_delimiter` argument in TEXTSPLIT:  `=SUM(IFERROR(--(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"[","]")),0))`

Comment: In my excel TEXTSPLIT OR TEXTBEFORE IS NOT available

Comment: Need another solution for excel 2013 or later

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Excel 2013:

```
=SUM(
    --LEFT(
        FILTERXML(
            "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1, "[", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
            "//s[contains(.,']')]"
        ),
        FIND(
            "]",
            FILTERXML(
                "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1, "[", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
                "//s[contains(.,']')]"
            )
        ) - 1
    )
)
```

- Use `FILTERXML` function to split on the "`[`" and ensure that the split portion contains a "`]`"
- Extract the numeric portion from the returned strings
- Use the double unary to convert from text to number
- `SUM` the results

This is an array formula. If you do not get a valid result, or an error,
in Excel 2013, you may need to enter/confirm an **array formula**, by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

***EDIT:** As noted in HELP for `FILTERXML` function, the first argument must be a **VALID** XML. If you have invalid characters, such as the ampersand (`&`), you must *escape* them for this function to work. That means using nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions. See below for an example related to the ampersand*

Also see this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/what-are-invalid-characters-in-xml) for a more complete list of invalid characters and their replacements.

```
=SUM(
    --LEFT(
        FILTERXML(
            "<t><s>" &
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(A1, "&", "&amp;"),
                    "[",
                    "</s><s>"
                ) & "</s></t>",
            "//s[contains(.,']')]"
        ),
        FIND(
            "]",
            FILTERXML(
                "<t><s>" &
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        SUBSTITUTE(A1, "&", "&amp;"),
                        "[",
                        "</s><s>"
                    ) & "</s></t>",
                "//s[contains(.,']')]"
            )
        ) - 1
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost working 95%. Few errors are there don't know why. I am pasting that txt here.

Comment: 11-05-2023 10:10:08 - Debasmita Mallick (Work Notes)
Internal connect : [10]

11-05-2023 09:44:22 - Debasmita Mallick (Work Notes)
Waiting for clouser confirmation from site.

10-05-2023 15:06:51 - Debasmita Mallick (Work Notes)
Site need | Seller User ID Password Needed (For FAT) for seller training purpose.
Same check with SN, he said we need confirmation from P&G once.

10-05-2023 15:03:24 - Debasmita Mallick (Work Notes)
Ach: [05]
Issue checking: [05]
Internal connect: [05]

Comment: I find error for this text why?

Comment: @TEJASKUMARBHAJIWALA The error is because your **XML** is not valid due to the presence of a disallowed character in your string (the ampersand `&`). Please read **HELP** for the `FILTERXML` function, and see my edit, for further information.

Comment: Thank you very much. #Superuser